# How to replace characters while writing in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, replace, special-characters

The goal is to replace some characters directly when written in the form input, not after submitting the form. Also, I would like to change the contrast of the replacing character to be kind of grey/less visible.

I came up with something like that (but not working infortunately):

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="test_input" id="test_input" onkeypress="myFunction()" required>
   <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  let str = document.getElementById("test_input").innerHTML; 
  let res = str.replace(/a/g, "b");
  document.getElementById("test_input").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You want to replace tabs, spaces and new lines in form with their corresponding characters i.e \t, \s, and \n ?

Comment: Well spotted, no for example the space would be represented by a point (not a full stop), the tab by an arrow etc. Ideally in a different color to show that it's a special character.

Comment: Why not just use replace with regex then? have you looked for it? you can also add styles while replacing to give it a color.

Comment: Not a bad idea. But it will not be replacing characters while I'm writing, I'll have to submit the form no ?

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in your code. Check out corrected code.
You need to correct your pattern.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="test_input" id="test_input" onkeyup="myFunction()" required>
   <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  let str = document.getElementById("test_input").value; 
  let res = str.replace(/a/g, "b");
  console.log(res)
  document.getElementById("test_input").value = res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Any idea about how to change the contrast of the replacing character to be kind of grey/less visible ?

Answer (score 1):

Try a cleaner solution that uses regular expressions:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[Search Expression]/flag,'New String');"/>
```

This solution prevents the user from typing a value outside the pattern established by the regex.

> Example:
> To remove all the **numbers** from "name" field:
> `<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[\d]/g, '');">`

Comment: Maybe the best event to attach this regex would be "onChange", because it prevents the user from bypassing "onKeyUp" (likewise "OnKeyDown", both keyboard raised events) with context menu ("right click").